# C++ Dudas sobre system("cls")

Tags: c++

Estudiando sobre C++ me he topado que no es bueno usar las funciones system() (como pause, o cls, etc)

**Tengo dos dudas:**

- Por que no es bueno usarlas?
- Encontre estos dos codigos:

*1.- Opcion:*

```
    void clear_screen()
    {
    DWORD n;                         /* Number of characters written */
    DWORD size;                      /* number of visible characters */
    COORD coord = {0};               /* Top left screen position */
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    /* Get a handle to the console */
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );

    /* Find the number of characters to overwrite */
    size = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

    /* Overwrite the screen buffer with whitespace */
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( h, TEXT ( ' ' ), size, coord, &n );
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute ( h, csbi.wAttributes, size, coord, &n );

    /* Reset the cursor to the top left position */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition ( h, coord );
    }
```

*2.- Opcion:*

```
    void clrscr()
    {
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi);

    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
    }
```

Cual de los dos seria el mejor reemplazo para la funcion "cls"?

**Nota:** *si tienen un mejor codigo para esto me seria de mucha utilidad que me lo pasen*

Comment: Dos preguntas en una, bueno, con respecto a la segunda, acá hay un ejemplo en la documentación de Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682022(VS.85).aspx Creo que vale la pena tener en cuenta la diferencia en los argumentos de llamada a FillConsoleOutputCharacter()

Comment: Nada mal, pero la verdad siento que leyera chino, jeje, aunque eso seria una tercera opcion, y mi duda es cual seria la mejor para trabajar

Comment: Dependiendo un poco del entorno, son las tres más o menos la misma. ¿Es tan urgente e importante limpiar la pantalla de tu programa de consola que no puede esperar a que aprendas los rudimentos del lenguaje?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Por que no es bueno usarlas?

Cuatro razones básicamente:

1. Estás invocando programas externos sobre los que no tienes ningún control. Puede suceder que diferentes versiones del Sistema Operativo posean diferentes versiones del programa, lo que puede hacer que tu código no funcione.
2. Son dependientes del SO. Hacer llamadas a `system` dificulta que puedas migrar el código entre Windows y Linux (por poner un ejemplo) ya que seguramente el programa no esté disponible en otros SO.
3. Es una alternativa muy lenta. Tener que ejecutar un programa externo mediante `system` implica que la consola debe interpretar tu entrada y ejecutar un programa externo... suelen existir alternativas mucho más rápidas y confiables, ya sea dentro del propio estándar o recurriendo a librerías de terceros.
4. La captura de resultados no es obvia. Llamar a un comando de consola para recuperar información para tu aplicación puede no ser algo obvio (la salida puede verse afectada por la configuración local del sistema, por ejemplo). Llamar a funciones nativas suele ser una mejor solución ya que los datos suelen venir estructurados.

> Cual de los dos seria el mejor reemplazo para la funcion "cls"?

Presupongo que los dos funcionarían. Como podrás observar son dos soluciones casi iguales (la primera digamos que es algo más completa). En cualquier caso son soluciones específicas para entornos Windows.

Comment: Ya veo, muchas gracias como siempre Eferion muy completa tu respuesta, es verdad que solo estoy trabajando en windows y estoy ignorando la portabilidad, aunque me hace preguntarme si es importante limpiar la pantalla o solo es cosa de estetica

Answer (score 4):

> Estudiando sobre C++ me he topado que no es bueno usar las funciones `system()` (como `pause`, o `cls`, etc). **¿Por qué no es bueno usarlas?**.

Normalmente, cuando en algún escrito o documento se desaconseja alguna práctica, se incluye una motivación para ello. Lee con mayor detalle tu fuente y deberían explicar el por qué... a no ser que lo hayas leído en un foro de internet, entonces podría darse esa información por sabida.

Sin conocer la motivación u objetivo del código es muy difícil saber si algo es aconsejable o no, pero a rasgos generales usar funciones específicas de sistema operativo se desaconseja pues hace que el [código no sea portable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidad). Pero que el código no sea portable es sólo un problema en caso de considerar que debiera serlo.

Así que, escogiendo funcionalidades específicas de sistema operativo (tus códigos de ejemplo apuntan a que estás programando para la consola de Windows) limitas tu código para dicho sistema operativo y lo haces incompatible para otros sistemas; si esto es lo que quieres no hay ningún problema, pero de no ser así **ese sería el motivo por el que no es bueno usar esas funciones** específicas de sistema operativo.

> Cual de los dos seria el mejor reemplazo para la funcion "`cls`"?

Ni idea. Tus códigos de ejemplo trabajan con la consola a bajo nivel sin delegar en llamadas a `system()`, si conocer tus motivaciones específicas es difícil definir si una aproximación es mejor que otra.

Sin saber más detalles, creo que la opción de `clear_screen` trabaja un poco menos que la de `clrscr` pues la primera sólo sobrescribe los caracteres escritos mientras que la segunda sobrescribe la pantalla completa.

Comment: ahora que lo mencionas pues si es verdad practicamente me estoy limitando a windows.. y sobre system pues leia que decia sobre cosas de seguridad pero no tengo idea como una pausa o limpiado de pantalla afecta a la seguridad