# ¿Cómo reemplazar system("pause") y system("cls") en C++?

Tags: c++, windows

## **Hola a Todos!**

¿Cómo puedo reemplazar las siguientes funciones o llamadas al Sistema Operativo?

```
system("CLS");
system("PAUSE");
```

Esto es debido a que me dijeron que, utilizar llamadas al SO es una mala práctica. Aunque siempre detectaba el SO por medio de condicionales y, dependiendo cual sea, modificaba el comando.

Muchos me dijeron que use la función `cin`, pero al usarla, puedo escribir normalmente. ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar esto?:

[image: :)]

Nota: No quiero usar la librería conio.h para resolver este problema.

Comment: Bueno... Soy nuevo en este lenguaje. La verdad, no quiero usar Conio.h ya que es un desafío personal. Luego, lo que no me gusta de la función CIN, es que uno puede escribir (Cosa natural de la función). Pero bueno, es lo que hay. No?

Comment: conio.h no es una biblioteca de C++ sino de C, además no es parte del estándar y sólo funciona en compiladores de MS-DOS, por lo que su uso no es recomendado si lo que quieres hacer es código portable y compatible entre diferentes sistemas operativos.

Comment: La pregunta fue inicialmente cerrada como duplicada de [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51744/250), pero la comunidad la reabrió.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explicación del problema

La manipulación del terminal difiere entre plataformas, por lo que requiere usar grupos de `#ifdef` para discriminar la implementación según la plataforma en la que se compile tu aplicación.

### Solución basada en bloques `#ifdef`

Puedes consultar cómo realizar la tarea en diferentes sistemas operativos en el [artículo enlazado](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/E6vU7k9E/). En él encontrarás código fuente de ejemplos relacionados con la forma en la que se deshabilitar el eco del teclado en windows y linux, por lo que puedes usar un bloque como el que sigue para conseguir tu propósito:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    /* Implementación en linux */
#elif _WIN32
    /* Implementación en windows */
#else
    /* Implementación para otros sistemas operativos o error */
#endif
```

Ejemplo (obtenido de [esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/reading-a-password-from-stdcin) de stackoverflow en inglés):

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

void SetStdinEcho(bool enable = true)
{
#ifdef WIN32
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    DWORD mode;
    GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);

    if( !enable )
        mode &= ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    else
        mode |= ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode );

#else
    struct termios tty;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty);
    if( !enable )
        tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    else
        tty.c_lflag |= ECHO;

    (void) tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty);
#endif
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Pulse una tecla para continuar";
    /* Desactivamos el eco */
    SetStdinEcho(false);
    /* Solicitamos la entrada de una cadena hasta pulsar enter */
    std::string buffer;
    std::cin >> buffer;
    /* Reactivamos el eco */
    SetStdinEcho(true);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Solución basada en `curses` (`ncurses`/`pdcurses`)

Por último, puedes usar `ncurses` o [`pdcurses` (otra alternativa multiplataforma)](https://sourceforge.net/p/pdcurses/code/ci/master/tree/win32/) para realizar el trabajo:

```
#include <string>
#include <curses.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   /* Habilitamos curses (ncurses/pdcurses) */
   initscr();
   printw("Pulse todo lo que quiera ahora...");
   /* Deshabilitamos el eco de pulsaciones del teclado */
   noecho();
   /* Esperamos hasta recibir un retorno del carro o 256 caracteres */
   char buffer[256];
   /* También podríamos usar getch() para esperar una única pulsación */
   getnstr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
   /* Habilitamos el eco de pulsaciones del teclado */
   echo();
   /* Finalizamos el uso de curses (ncurses/pdcurses) */
   endwin();
   return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo hago uso de [`getnstr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getnstr) para obtener cualquier combinación de teclas hasta encontrar un retorno del carro, como [`getch()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch). Podrías usar funciones que leen tecla a tecla, pero ésta me pareció la más rápida para el ejemplo.

Por último el trabajo que deseas lo realizan las funciones [`noecho()` y `echo()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/noecho) que deshabilitan y habilitan respectivamente el eco de pulsaciones del teclado.

Comment: me has ahorrado escribir mucho más de lo que me apetecía en este momento :)

Comment: Gracias @eferion . Aún quedaría implementar el borrado del terminal (`cls`) para completar la respuesta, pero sólo me molestaré en agregarlo si hay respuesta, tampoco me gusta escribir por escribir sin saber si se ajusta a lo que busca el autor ;).

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Se ajusta totalmente a lo que yo busco!

Answer (score 0):

Si bien no soy experto (ni algo similar) en C++, voy a responder tu pregunta con lo poco que sé debido a que en su momento yo también tuve similares inquietudes respecto al usar las funciones `system("pause")` y `system("cls")`.

Para empezar, en relación a la función `system("pause")` puedes utilizar la función `cin.get()`, la cual básicamente te permite leer un carácter que ingreses desde el teclado (para información más exacta puedes revisar el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10346/63114)). La manera de utilizarlo sería similar al ejemplo dado por el usuario akko en la otra respuesta.

O también puedes utilizarlo del siguiente modo, en combinación con la [función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21822/63114) `cin.ignore()`:

```
//Líneas de código
//Lo que viene a continuación es para indicarle al usuario como salir del programa
cin.ignore();
cout << "Presione la tecla Enter para salir del programa."; //puedes cambiar tu mensaje
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Ahora, con respecto a la función `system("cls)`, pues lamentablemente no existe en C++ una función que te permita "limpiar" la pantalla. Sino me equivoco, tengo entendido que C++ fue creado para ser utilizado de la manera más general posible en distintas plataformas, muchas de las cuales ni siquiera poseen una pantalla o algo equivalente. En el caso de que se pueda implementar una función que se encargue de limpiar la pantalla, tal función necesariamente debe ser dependiende del SO y por tanto, no sería portable.

Según he leído, en caso de que utilices un SO derivado de Unix puedes utilizar la librería `ncurses` donde existe una función para limpiar la pantalla. En el caso de Windows puedes utilizar la librería `pdcurses`, que es análogo a la librería `ncurses` (quiero señalar que yo no he utilizado tales librerías así que no puedo garantizar nada más allá de lo que he leído). Sin embargo, como ya escribí líneas arriba, tales soluciones son dependientes del SO.

Una alternativa que puede funcionar en Windows para limpiar la pantalla es emular lo que hace `system("cls")`. A continuación te dejo el código (que lo saqué de [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51744/63114)):

```
void clear_screen()
    {
    DWORD n;                         /* Number of characters written */
    DWORD size;                      /* number of visible characters */
    COORD coord = {0};               /* Top left screen position */
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    /* Get a handle to the console */
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );

    /* Find the number of characters to overwrite */
    size = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

    /* Overwrite the screen buffer with whitespace */
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( h, TEXT ( ' ' ), size, coord, &n );
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute ( h, csbi.wAttributes, size, coord, &n );

    /* Reset the cursor to the top left position */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition ( h, coord );
    }
```

Yo mismo lo he probado y funciona bastante bien.

Comment: Gracias... Pero no es lo que busco. Acabo de agregar una edición a mi pregunta que explica mejor lo que busco :)

Comment: @MathiasHilgert ok ya veo. Si se me ocurre algo editaré mi respuesta. En todo caso, espero que al menos te haya servido lo que puse respecto a la función `system("cls")` :)

Comment: al usuario que me dio downvote: ¿tendría la amabilidad de indicar porque lo hizo?

Comment: Yo podría votarte negativo por intentar emular el comportamiento de PAUSE con `cin`... que hasta que no presiones enter no te de vuelve el control y encima imprime valores en la consola... desde luego su comportamiento no es ni de lejos un sustituto digno

Comment: @eferion ahí tienes razón, sin embargo mi respuesta fue hecha para la pregunta original del OP (donde no indicaba que su problema era que podía seguir escribiendo). De todos modos gracias por aclararme el fallo de mi respuesta.

Comment: @Xam es una sugerencia acerca de los negativos... si la respuesta tiene errores es probable que alguien la vote en negativo

Comment: Piensa que `cin.get` no devuelve el control hasta que se presiona *enter*... como solo estás procesando un caracter tendrás, al menos, que limpiar el buffer de entrada para evitar lecturas sucias posteriores... por otro lado piensa que `cin` muestra lo que escribes por pantalla... luego el resultado será un poco feo

Answer (score -1):

Para sustituir `system("pause")`puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
void pausa(string msj){                                                 
    if(msj == "") msj = "Presiona Enter para continuar";                
    cout << msj << endl;                                                
    cin.get();                                                          
    cin.clear();                                                        
}
```

Comment: Gracias... Pero no es lo que busco. Acabo de agregar una edición a mi pregunta que explica mejor lo que busco :)

Comment: El problema que tiene `cin` es que no devuelve el control hasta que se presiona *enter*... da igual que quieras capturar un solo caracter o 300...